# How can I count how many times something appears in my object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I need to see how many times a code appears in the Customs key and then display the code under (name:) and the amount of times it appears in (data:). I think im close please see snippet below.  So all I want to see when I console log data is something like - name:123213 data:22.

```js
// Here is my json object 
var json = [
    "G": "PIF",
    "H": "FOB",
    "I": "NINGBO",
    "J": "NGB",
    "K": "2014-10-01",
    "M": "2014-10-01",
    "Y": "LIVERPOOL",
    "zp": "LIV",
    "N": "2014-11-09",
    "P": "2014-11-09",
    "R": "2014-11-09T12:01",
    "V": true,
    "zk": " ",
    "zo": "7",
    "Customs": [
        "39210000"
    ],
    "LatLon": {}
},
//   ...... etc

// Here is my failed attempt 
$(document).ready(function () {
    var CommodityCounts = {};
    var Commoditycds  = [];
    var totalCount    = 0;

    //loop through the object
    $.each(json, function(key, val) {
        var Commoditycd = val["Customs"];

        //build array of unique country names
        if ($.inArray(Commoditycd, Commoditycds) == -1) {
            Commoditycds.push(Commoditycd);
        }

        //add or increment a count for the country name
        if (typeof CommodityCounts[Commoditycd] == 'undefined') {
            CommodityCounts[Commoditycd] = 1;
        }
        else {
            CommodityCounts[Commoditycd]++;
        }

        //increment the total count so we can calculate %
        totalCount++;
    });

    //console.log(Commoditycds);
    var data = [];

    //loop through unique countries to build data for chart
    $.each(Commoditycds, function(key, Commoditycd) {
        data.push({
            name: Commoditycd,
            data: CommodityCounts
        });
    });
    console.log(data);
});

// Need the data to be show like (name of the code and how many times it appears in my json object-  name: '123123', data: [83]
```

Comment: `name:123213 data:22` How is it relevant regarding your posted array? I don't get what is expected behaviour. EDIT: i think you want name to match Customs property but still not clear what should be data and what you expect if more than one object in array. You have to edit your question with an MCVE replicating issue

Comment: Just FYI, what you have is an array of objects, not JSON.

Comment: Can you have more than one number in the `customs` arrays?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nice one

Comment: where do you get `123213` from? and why is `data: 22` ?

Comment: @NinaScholz thats just an example data could be anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```js
var result = json.reduce(function(a, x) {
  x.Customs.forEach(function(c) {
    a[c] = a[c] ? a[c] + 1 : 1
  });
  return a;
}, {});

result = Object.keys(result).reduce(function(a, key) {
  return a.concat([{name: key, data: result[key]}])
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

---

**For reference:**

- [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Understand JavaScript array reduce](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/javascript-array-reduce)

Comment: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined --- how are you targeting the "Customs" key?

Comment: aaaa I see that works :) but I think mine is failing because some sections don't contain a Customs key.

Comment: @user5554551 you can either add a check inside reduce or apply a filter before reducing, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/hjrtx4rf/3/

Answer (score 2):

My version is very similar to Rūdolfs' except I use `map` instead of `reduce` to build the new array. It also checks that the `Customs` property exists.

```
var out = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
    if (c.Customs) {
        c.Customs.forEach(function (el) {
            p[el] = (p[el] || 0) + 1;
        });
    }
    return p;
}, {});

var out = Object.keys(out).map(function (key) {
  return { name: key, value: out[key] };
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ufxdcxd/3/)